# Specify/fix JDK used by wsimport in Ant build

Tags: java, netbeans, ant, wsimport, netbeans-14

I've got a NetBeans 14 free-form project using Ant. It utilizes `wsimport` in its `build.xml`, and a lot of the targets depend on `wsimport`. After ending up with several JDKs (at least 1.8 and 17) I'm having trouble building, from `wsimport` chosing the wrong JDK.

In the `build.xml` (extracts):

```
<taskdef name="wsimport" classname="com.sun.tools.ws.ant.WsImport">
    <classpath>
            <pathelement location="${lib}/jaxws22/jaxws-tools.jar"/>
        </classpath>
    </taskdef>

<target name="wsimport">
    <wsimport
        wsdl="http://address/to/wsdl.xml"
        catalog="${metainf}/jax-ws-catalog.xml"
        destdir="${release}"
        sourcedestdir="${src-gen}"
        keep="true"
        extension="true"
        verbose="true">
        <depends file="${metainf}/jax-ws-catalog.xml"/>
        <depends file="${wsdl}/wsdl.xml"/>
        <produces dir="${src-gen}"/>
    </wsimport>
</target>

<target name="compile" depends="init,wsimport" description="compile the source">
    <javac ... />
</target>
```

The problem is that when running `wsimport` seems to select JDK17, while I want it to select JDK1.8. The output is this:

```
command line: wsimportC:\path\to\jdk-17.0.2\bin\java.exe ... http://address/to/wsdl.xml
```

Which gives:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/org/apache/xml/internal/resolver/CatalogManager
    at com.sun.tools.ws.wscompile.WsimportOptions.parseArguments(WsimportOptions.java:317)
    ...
```

Which I've got down to not working with JDK 17. How can I make `wsimport` use the correct JDK in this scenario?